# syntax error, unexpected '<' when trying to display query results into a table. PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Im trying to display information from my database that's been fetched by a MySql query. I set this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\search.php on line 14
```

**Here is the code for search.php**

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['searchterm'])){
mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
mysql_select_db("videos");

$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchterm']));

$find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `keywords` LIKE'%$search%'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_videos))
{
    $name = $row['name'];

    echo "<table">";
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$name</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo  "<td>$name</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
}
?>
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar { font-size: 125% }
</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Network TV | search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/3.1.1/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Network TV</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="\1\index.php">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

I already have the form setup to POST the information to this page. When the information is display it's just in a list hanging off the top left side of the screen, i'm trying to display it in a table in the center of the. Here is some examples of things I tried.

```
echo "<table style=text-align:center">"";
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$name</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo  "<td>$name</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

This gives me error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"<table style="' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\search.php on line 13`

Then I tried.

```
        echo "<table style=""width:100%">";
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Jill</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo  "<td>Eve</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

and I got error 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"width:100%"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\search.php on line 14`

I have no idea whats wrong. any help is really appreciated

**Marked as duplicate**
I have no idea what i'm fixing so unfortunately its no help to me. im sure it will help someone else later down the line.

**Image and update**
Here is an image how it looks now. 
[image]

as you can see the 'Name of movies' is being repeated each time.

**Code update**

```
echo '<table style="width:100%">';
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Name of movie</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo  "<td>$name</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

**Update 2**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['searchterm'])){
mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
mysql_select_db("videos");

$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchterm']));

$find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `keywords` LIKE'%$search%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($find_videos, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
{

    $name = $row['name'];
}
}
}
?>
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar { font-size: 125% }
</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Network TV | search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/3.1.1/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Network TV</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="\1\index.php">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
        <div class="v-center">
                <h1 class="text-center" style="color:white">Welcome to Network TV</h1>
                <table class="table" style="width:10%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Movie name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: In line 14 you wrote echo "`<table">";`... Remove the second " and it will work

Comment: Now noting is being displayed, the error has gone but no results are being shown.

Comment: Your HTML is badly-quoted. In the first code example you have `echo "<table">";` - there are three double quotes. You want `echo "<table>"`. In the final code example you have `echo "<table style=""width:100%">";`. Using the same style of quotes for both your PHP and HTML code will confuse the PHP parser, so you should differentiate between the two. E.g. `echo '<table style="width:100%">';`

Comment: Updated post please have a read, thanks

Comment: @OliverKetley So what do you get now with your updated code?

Comment: Hey, it displays one result only, the last entry to the database that is.

Comment: if you could help it would be amazing

Comment: @OliverKetley Well you still have the table tag and these stuff in your loop. So move everything out of the loop which you don't want to have in there, e.g. `echo "<table style='width:100'>";
 echo "<tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_videos)) {
  echo  "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
 }
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>";`

Comment: @OliverKetley Now you show us some different code. But with your code in update 2 your problem is, that you overwrite the variable in each iteration of your while loop. So change your while loop to something like this: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_videos)) { $names[] = $row["name"];}` then later, when you want to use your fetched names change your current code: `<tr>
                                <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                            </tr>` to something like this: `<tr>
 <?php foreach($names as $name) { ?>
 <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
 <?php } ?>
 </tr>`

Comment: I'm extremely new to programming, iv'e replaced the while statement and nothing happens, it displays nothing. I dont know where to put the rest of the code you supplied.

Comment: @OliverKetley Your code should look something like this: http://pastebin.com/m5RL7u7z

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83637/discussion-between-rizier123-and-oliver-ketley).